# linux kernel config / module for Kobo eReader

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

Running one of my custom kernels, I can't get my Kobo Aura HD eReader automounted. It's recognized, but that's all. Using a Debian standard kernel, it works OK.

I could now diff the configs, but too may options differ (there are 14.000 config options in 4.0 after all).

Q: What modules are needed for a Kobo Aura HD eReader to be (auto)mounted in the 4.7 line?

Answer (score 1):

First by trying run this

```
scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl > .config-wherevername
```

Then

```
cat .config-wherevername | grep =m | wc -l
```

You are able to make a custom .config by using that script command above.

If you see more than 1K of modules, then try it again.

Another method is whose modules were loaded by kernel.

```
cat /proc/modules | wc -l
```

pd: if you see my English bad, I apologize, cause it is not my first or main language.